# Slick Slider does not work with Bootstrap Tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I want to slide the images using slick slider. I used the Bootstrap tab menu and each tab has to show a slick slider properly. But I have a problem. The first tab content shows slick slider without any problem but when I click the second tab it shows only one image. It does not work properly. How can I fix this problem?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <title>Focus Education</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" integrity="sha512-wR4oNhLBHf7smjy0K4oqzdWumd+r5/+6QO/vDda76MW5iug4PT7v86FoEkySIJft3XA0Ae6axhIvHrqwm793Nw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" integrity="sha512-17EgCFERpgZKcm0j0fEq1YCJuyAWdz9KUtv1EjVuaOz8pDnh/0nZxmU6BBXwaaxqoi9PQXnRWqlcDB027hgv9A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
</head>
<style>
  * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #35bb60;
  }
  
  div.your-class {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  .nav-tabs .nav-link {
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .wrap-modal-slider {
    padding: 0 30px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  
  .wrap-modal-slider.open {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  .your-class {
    width: 726px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  /* Arrows */
  
  .slick-prev,
  .slick-next {
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    color: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
  }
  
  .slick-prev:hover,
  .slick-prev:focus,
  .slick-next:hover,
  .slick-next:focus {
    color: transparent;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
  }
  
  .slick-prev:hover:before,
  .slick-prev:focus:before,
  .slick-next:hover:before,
  .slick-next:focus:before {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  .slick-prev.slick-disabled:before,
  .slick-next.slick-disabled:before {
    opacity: .25;
  }
  
  .slick-prev:before,
  .slick-next:before {
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1;
    opacity: .75;
    color: white;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  }
  
  .slick-prev {
    left: -25px;
  }
  
  [dir='rtl'] .slick-prev {
    right: -25px;
    left: auto;
  }
  
  .slick-prev:before {
    content: '←';
  }
  
  [dir='rtl'] .slick-prev:before {
    content: '→';
  }
  
  .slick-next {
    right: -25px;
  }
  
  [dir='rtl'] .slick-next {
    right: auto;
    left: -25px;
  }
  
  .slick-next:before {
    content: '→';
  }
  
  [dir='rtl'] .slick-next:before {
    content: '←';
  }
  /* Dots */
  
  .slick-dotted.slick-slider {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  
  .slick-dots {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .slick-dots li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .slick-dots li button {
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
  }
  
  .slick-dots li button:hover,
  .slick-dots li button:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
  
  .slick-dots li button:hover:before,
  .slick-dots li button:focus:before {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  .slick-dots li button:before {
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-size: 6px;
    line-height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    content: '•';
    text-align: center;
    opacity: .25;
    color: black;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  }
  
  .slick-dots li.slick-active button:before {
    opacity: .75;
    color: black;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">New</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Popular</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Recommend</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
      <div class="your-class">
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/ffffff/000000" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/000000/ffffff" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/ffffff/000000" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/000000/ffffff" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/ffffff/000000" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/000000/ffffff" alt=""></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
      <div class="your-class">
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/ffffff/000000" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/000000/ffffff" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/ffffff/000000" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/000000/ffffff" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/ffffff/000000" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/000000/ffffff" alt=""></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
      <div class="your-class">
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/ffffff/000000" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/000000/ffffff" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/ffffff/000000" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/000000/ffffff" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/ffffff/000000" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/000000/ffffff" alt=""></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.your-class').slick({
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 3
    });
  });

  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    $('.your-class').slick('setPosition');
  })
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: You have a few problems up there. First, all scripts and style elements should be inside the head or body. It's invalid HTML to have them between the head and the body. Then, you're loading jQuery twice. This can cause problems and is usually unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my first impression was that there seemed to be a bit "too much" going on. I went through and simplified some things. The two biggest issues that caused it not to function as expected was you need to include `active` on each `tab-pane` class. Only include `show` on the "New" tab since that is the one you want to display on load.

Simplified JS ~

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.your-class').slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
    });
});
```

See it in action here ~

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <title>Focus Education</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" integrity="sha512-wR4oNhLBHf7smjy0K4oqzdWumd+r5/+6QO/vDda76MW5iug4PT7v86FoEkySIJft3XA0Ae6axhIvHrqwm793Nw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" integrity="sha512-17EgCFERpgZKcm0j0fEq1YCJuyAWdz9KUtv1EjVuaOz8pDnh/0nZxmU6BBXwaaxqoi9PQXnRWqlcDB027hgv9A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
</head>
<style>
  * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #35bb60;
  }
  
  div.your-class {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  .nav-tabs .nav-link {
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .wrap-modal-slider {
    padding: 0 30px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  
  .wrap-modal-slider.open {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  .your-class {
    width: 726px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  /* Arrows */
  
  .slick-prev,
  .slick-next {
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    color: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
  }
  
  .slick-prev:hover,
  .slick-prev:focus,
  .slick-next:hover,
  .slick-next:focus {
    color: transparent;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
  }
  
  .slick-prev:hover:before,
  .slick-prev:focus:before,
  .slick-next:hover:before,
  .slick-next:focus:before {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  .slick-prev.slick-disabled:before,
  .slick-next.slick-disabled:before {
    opacity: .25;
  }
  
  .slick-prev:before,
  .slick-next:before {
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1;
    opacity: .75;
    color: white;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  }
  
  .slick-prev {
    left: -25px;
  }
  
  [dir='rtl'] .slick-prev {
    right: -25px;
    left: auto;
  }
  
  .slick-prev:before {
    content: '←';
  }
  
  [dir='rtl'] .slick-prev:before {
    content: '→';
  }
  
  .slick-next {
    right: -25px;
  }
  
  [dir='rtl'] .slick-next {
    right: auto;
    left: -25px;
  }
  
  .slick-next:before {
    content: '→';
  }
  
  [dir='rtl'] .slick-next:before {
    content: '←';
  }
  /* Dots */
  
  .slick-dotted.slick-slider {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  
  .slick-dots {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .slick-dots li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .slick-dots li button {
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
  }
  
  .slick-dots li button:hover,
  .slick-dots li button:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
  
  .slick-dots li button:hover:before,
  .slick-dots li button:focus:before {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  .slick-dots li button:before {
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-size: 6px;
    line-height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    content: '•';
    text-align: center;
    opacity: .25;
    color: black;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  }
  
  .slick-dots li.slick-active button:before {
    opacity: .75;
    color: black;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">New</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Popular</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Recommend</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
      <div class="your-class">
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/ffffff/000000" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/000000/ffffff" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/ffffff/000000" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/000000/ffffff" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/ffffff/000000" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/000000/ffffff" alt=""></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade active" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
      <div class="your-class">
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/ffffff/000000" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/000000/ffffff" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/ffffff/000000" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/000000/ffffff" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/ffffff/000000" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/000000/ffffff" alt=""></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade active" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
      <div class="your-class">
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/ffffff/000000" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/000000/ffffff" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/ffffff/000000" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/000000/ffffff" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/ffffff/000000" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/242x300/000000/ffffff" alt=""></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.your-class').slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
    });
});
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: The `active` class should only be on the pane that's actually active.

Comment: Please put the code in the respective snippet panels so it's not one giant gob.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments I solved my problem thanks the responds that up there Thank you sooo much:):)